Switching a solid state relay when millivolt difference is detected
I have this circuit that switches a solid state relay whenever a difference of a few millivolts is detected between a \$V_{IN}\$ & \$V_{REF}\$.

Full schematic here
The above left circuit works well enough, but as I already stated, it ought to trigger the solid state relay at millivolts range; not at the typical \$V_{BE}\$ of the PNP.
So, as you can see at the right side, I replaced the PNP with a (hopefully sensible) comparator from LTSpice's native library. For the comparator's supply, let's just go under the assumption that it's supply range goes up to \$V_{DD}\$.
Yet, this is the output on \$V_{LOAD1}\$ against \$V_{LOAD2}\$:

Ignoring that the model has it's shortcomings such as using optocouplers in place of a real solid state relay (as LTSpice has no native library for SSRs) & the need for a flyback diode on a said optocoupler (representing an SSR), that's supposed be solid state either way (no back EMFs), how do I make the \$V_{LOAD2}\$ look like \$V_{LOAD1}\$? Maybe I should use a Schmitt trigger so I can have larger thresholds?

how is "use the second circuit" not a good answer?

Can you show V_in and V_ref in your simulation?  It's not terribly meaningful to just look at the outputs

your post contains inconsistent information ... first paragraph says switches a solid state relay whenever a difference of a few millivolts is detected ... second paragraph says as I already stated, it ought to trigger the solid state relay at millivolts range, which seems like a contradiction ... please clarify your post

Are you applying 120VDC supply to a comparator with 5.5V absolute maximum supply? And +/-60V peak to one of the inputs? That's likely to end.. badly. Inputs should stay within the supply rails for most comparators to avoid damage. Even less for many if you also expect them to function. Also note that 4N25 has 20% minimum CTR so you need to put 5 or 10x as much current into the LED as you expect out of the (70V rated) phototransistor.
